# Sitecore : login content editor as visitor

Tags: authentication, sitecore, content-editor

Setting: 
We have a Sitecore extranet/intranet.
We have 100-ish user who need to access the intranet.
We have 10 content editor licenses.

I would like to login a user ( with the "sitecore/Sitecore Client User" role ) into the intranet.
However this user should simply get his/her read rights for the intranet and not be seen as a content editor ( the Sitecore Client User role automaticly makes the user a content editor )

If i use Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(user, false); will sitecore automaticly see this user as a content editor and thus use up one of the licenses ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to setup your site to have a separate domain for the delivery. Then create your own login page for the site that uses the ASP.Net membership API to log the user in. It will use the domain specified in the site settings. These users will not count against the content editor licences, but you are still able to add security to the items to give the users read access to the content.

This article https://www.markstiles.net/Blog/2011/12/26/setting-up-a-sitecore-extranet.aspx is an older one, but the principles still apply. You can also look at http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_usletter.pdf

Note that this will not log them into the content editor or the desktop. If you need the users to be able to log into the content editor, that is a valid use of a licence, your only option there would be to get more licences.